# How to Redirect to Non Secure Pages without message warning in Apps?

Tags: facebook

On Monday all of my apps that was being redirected from my secure SSL site to non secure websites was giving a security warning.  Is there anyway to redirect from secure websites to non secure ones without a security warning?

Answer (score 0):

Secure Canvas URL is required when Sandbox Mode is disabled after 1st oct 2011. 
so you cant redirect https to http beacause its manage by facebook if user enabled secure browsing you need SSL to avoid this warning .

Comment: _“after 1st oct.”_ – yes, and to be precise, Oct. 1st __last year__ …

Comment: Even in sandbox mode its still giving the warning.

Comment: Change ur profile security setting ans unchecko enable secure browsing.